# GWT Designer with smartGWT : No palettes for smart widgets (XML UIBinder mode)

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, smartgwt, gwt-designer

I added and configured SmartGWT in my project into eclipse.
I have no news SmartGWT palettes that appear in the GWT developer.
Yet, according to the official documentation of google, widgets palettes should appear automatically.

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/smartgwt.html

Note : In fact, the SmartGWT palettes appear if I use GWT Designer with java file. But I would like use with XML file, is it possible ? GWT Designer support SmartGWT with XML ui:UiBinder ?

Versions : GWT 2.2 / GWT Designer 2.2.1 (I tested beta and not beta) / SmartGWT 2.4 / eclipse Helios / maven 3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I heard that in the UiBinder mode the palette will not appear, not sure why. I personally like to have my views in different Java files that I just inject into the module. I unfortunately use Indigo and it seems the Indigo support isn't there yet. Will have to download and install Helios over the weekend.

I found this [post](http://code.google.com/p/gxt-uibinder/issues/detail?id=4) when I had the same problem with GXT, it seems there isn't a real standard for UiBinder, so every vendor makes their own decisions.